# Count multiple columns in Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm studying laravel query builder's "count"
I would like to count column name 'q12a' and 'q18a'

I can count total records useing below code.

```
public function count()
{
    $total_projects = Book::count();
    return view('count')->with(['total'=>$total_projects]);
 }
```

However I'm having problem multiple columns
I had been searching count multiple columns and trying below code and I got

> Error Call to a member function count() on int

Dear matiaslauriti helping me and I change code as below.

> UPDATED

```
public function sum_ttl()
{
    $q18a_count = DB::table('books')->count('q12a')->count('q18a');
    return view('sum_ttl', compact('q12a','q18a'));
 }
```

Could you teach me how to write correct code at controller and blade file please?

Comment: Doing `DB::('books')` means nothing in PHP, that is as PHP syntax error... You should be doing `DB::table('books')` and still, use models not raw queries...

Comment: Dear @matiaslauriti  Thank you very much for helping me. I fix my code. and I got another error. could you take a look my update?

Comment: I have added an answer to your problem. `count` will return an `int`, so you will have to do 2 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. [`count`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates) will return the count of your desired columns (`*` by default). So you want to do something like:

```php
public function sum_ttl()
{
    $q12aCount = Books::count('q12a');
    $q18aCount = Books::count('q18a');

    return view('sum_ttl', compact('q12aCount', 'q18aCount'));
}
```

If you want to share the exact SQL query you want to execute, I could try to "translate" it to Eloquent.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is perfect! I really appreciate you doing this. I had been stucking couple of weeks so I'm really happy now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem ! Make sure to read the documentation, everything is explained there !